# Encoding conversions UTF-8 Cp1252 and ISO-8859-1

Tags: java, encoding, vb6, iso-8859-1

Ok so I have a Visual Basic 6 applicacion which I assume works with Cp1252 encoding (they don't change it so I'm guessing that's the default) which does the following

Equivalent code in Java:

```
            String key = "THEKEY";
            int x = 1;
            int asciiVal, asciiKey, asciiTot;       
            for(int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++){
                asciiVal = (int)frase.charAt(i);
                asciiKey = (int)key.charAt(x-1);
                x += x;
                if(x > key.length()){
                    x = 1;
                }       
                asciiTot = asciiVal + asciiKey;

                if(asciiTot > 255)
                    asciiTot -= 255;

                resultado = resultado + new String(Character.toChars(asciiTot));            
            }
```

frase is the String being encoded. Now, I'm sure this code is equivalent because I've tested my results against the one in the VB app and it does the same thing.

The decrypt method looks like that following:

```
            String key = "THEKEY";
            int x = 1;
            int asciiVal, asciiKey, asciiTot;       
            for(int i = 0; i < frase.length(); i++){
                asciiVal = (int)frase.charAt(i);    
                asciiKey = (int)key.charAt(x-1);                
                x += x;
                if(x > key.length()){
                    x = 1;
                }
                asciiTot = asciiVal - asciiKey;

                if(asciiTot < 0)
                    asciiTot += 255;                
                resultado = resultado + new String(Character.toChars(asciiTot));            
            }
```

This method also tested positive in the tests against the VB6 app.

So now here's the thing, the VB app grabs a String encrypts it and saves it on a MSSQL database whose target column is in Modern_Spanish_CI_AS. So I'm assuming The string undergoes the following

Cp1252 converts to ISO-8859-1 as it goes into the database.

My Java application works in UTF-8 encoding so I did the following to retrieve the column

```
        String frase = new String(rs.getString("FoliosTOTALES_Libres").getBytes("Cp1252"), "ISO-8859-1");
```

However this String after being decrypted doesn't result exactly as it should(certain characters miss). I've made the Java App give me an ASCII array of the string as I receive it from the database and a couple of ascii values are out of the 255 range (which shouldnt happen) that's why I blame the encoding, but I don't know where I could be going wrong.

Comment: Why do you convert it to Cp1252 and then to ISO-8859-1?  Can't you just do it directly? `String frase = new String(rs.getString("FoliosTOTALES_Libres").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));`

Comment: I've tried this, this goes way off in the conversion

Comment: From description it seems that the problem is in VB6 (or VB6 to database). But only Java code is present. Would you add a VB6 sample?